# Get Sql Server Table using Table Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had a scenario where I need `sql server object` (or `TABLE` to be specific), and I have only `table name.`
I try using `SQL functions`, but not helped my cause.

E.g. I have a table called USERS contains column userid, and username. 
Sample data is: USERS(1, 'user 1') USERS(2, 'user 2').

Another table called RequestsGenerated contains column entityTableName, columnName, entityid, and requestName. Sample data is: RequestsGenerated('dbo.USERS', 'userid', 1, 'Leave Request')

What i want to see in my resultset is all requests name with appropriate users

Sample data/queries copied below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMPUSERS(userid int, username varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #TMPUSERS VALUES (1, 'user 1')
INSERT INTO #TMPUSERS VALUES (2, 'user 2')

CREATE TABLE #TMPREQUESTS(requestid int, requesttype varchar(50), tablename varchar(50), columnname varchar(50), entityid int)
INSERT INTO #TMPREQUESTS VALUES (1, 'Leave Request', 'dbo.#TMPUSERS', 'userid', 1)

--select statement here, that return all records from #tmprequests with username

DROP TABLE #TMPREQUESTS
DROP TABLE #TMPUSERS
```

Comment: I am not clear about your requirement. Can you show a sample output?

Comment: @bmsqldev if I have a table USERS contains column userid int, and username varchar(50), then I am expecting my function to return SELECT * FROM USERS (where USERS should be the input param). So my output will be a resultset that contains all data from all columns (i.e. userid, and username)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to resolve this problem. Sharing, may be it helps someone else:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMPUSERS(userid int, username varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #TMPUSERS VALUES (1, 'user 1')
INSERT INTO #TMPUSERS VALUES (2, 'user 2')

CREATE TABLE #TMPREQUESTS(requestid int, requesttype varchar(50), tablename varchar(50), columnname varchar(50), entityid int)
INSERT INTO #TMPREQUESTS VALUES (1, 'Leave Request', 'dbo.#TMPUSERS', 'userid', 1)

--select statement here, that return all records from #tmprequests with username
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'select tr.requestid, tr.requesttype, tu.username from #TMPREQUESTS tr INNER JOIN ' + tablename + ' tu ON tr.entityid = tu.' + columnname  from #TMPREQUESTS
EXEC(@SQL)

DROP TABLE #TMPREQUESTS
DROP TABLE #TMPUSERS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql to get this result.

```
DECLARE @T_TABLE AS nvarchar(100) = 'TBL_ITEM_MASTER'
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM '+ @T_TABLE)
```

Or try something like this,

```
DECLARE @T_TABLE_RSLT AS nvarchar(2000) 
SELECT TOP 1 @T_TABLE_RSLT = ('SELECT U.*,RG.requestName FROM '+entityTableName+ ' U 
    INNER JOIN RequestsGenerated RG ON RG.entityid = U.'+columnName +'')
FROM RequestsGenerated
EXEC (@T_TABLE_RSLT)
```

Comment: I already try that, But it does not fit in my scenario, as I have to my function in JOIN, and passing this query to join return error: "Invalid object name"

Comment: E.g. I have a table called USERS contains column userid, and username. Sample data is:
USERS(1, 'user 1')
USERS(2, 'user 2')
Another table called RequestsGenerated contains column entityTableName, and columnName, entityid, requestName. Sample data is:
RequestsGenerated('dbo.USERS', 'userid', 1, 'Leave Request')

What i want to see in my resultset is all requests name with appropriate users

Comment: another script added

Comment: Since we do not have predefined entityTableName and columnName, i guess,  i can't use your solution. (as per my edited question).